# What is a Plugin?

Tags: android, browser, webkit

I have a doubt regarding the plugins. what is a plug-in if possible please explain in context of browser.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)

Answer (score 2):

> In computing, a plug-in (or plugin) is a set of software components
>   that adds specific abilities to a larger software application. If
>   supported, plug-ins enable customizing the functionality of an
>   application. For example, plug-ins are commonly used in web browsers
>   to play video, scan for viruses, and display new file types.
>   Well-known plug-ins examples include Adobe Flash Player, QuickTime,
>   and Microsoft Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

It's a piece of software which can be hooked to work with a large software system.
Quote Wiki

"In computing, a plug-in (or plugin) is a set of software components that adds specific abilities to a larger software application. If supported, plug-ins enable customizing the functionality of an application. For example, plug-ins are commonly used in web browsers to play video, scan for viruses, and display new file types. Well-known plug-ins examples include Adobe Flash Player, QuickTime, and Microsoft Silverlight."

Answer (score 0):

```
Plug-in applications are programs that can easily be installed and used as part
 of your Web browser.
```

Example
you can find several oplgins for mozilla for chat application or creating notes etc